# Issue with Bootstrap Anchor Tag within Paragraph Tag

Tags: html, css

I have a simple issue regarding an HTML Anchor Tag within a Paragraph Tag.  This is a Bootstrap Template.

The problem is occurring when viewing the webpage in Small and Extra Small ViewPorts.

[Here is the Website](http://www.davincispainting.com)

The Anchor Tag Button shifts outside of the container, whenever scaling down to smaller viewports.  I need the Anchor to remain within the container, but I'm not clear on what I need to modify.

[image]

```
<div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive rounded-2x img-width-175 hidden-xs" style="float: left; margin-top: 2px;" src="Images/Home/Exterior2.jpg" alt="Exterior Painter">
   <h3 style="background-color: #FF6D00; margin-top: -2px; float: inherit; text-decoration: underline;"><i>Exterior Painting</i></h3>
   <p class="text-justify" style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.07em; background-color: #FF6D00; padding-left: 8px; padding-bottom: 6px; margin-top: -10px; line-height: 1.37em;">
      Whether your Home is new, or perhaps a farmhouse that was built 80 years ago...
      <a href="Interior-Painting" type="button" class="btn-u" style="font-size: 11px; line-height: .8em; float: right; margin-right: 12px; background: #d96006">Exterior Painting Services</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that those buttons are floated right which takes them out of the document flow. You could look into using a [clearfix](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/). Also, I would suggest adding some padding to those content blocks, the arrows cover up the text making it hard to read.

Comment: you need to clear floats AKA clearfix -- add `.item:after{ display:table; content:''; clear: both}` to CSS

Comment: @APAD1 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added clearfix to the P Tag:

```
<p class="text-justify clearfix" style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.07em; background-color: #5AA608; padding-left: 8px; padding-bottom: 6px; margin-top: -10px; line-height: 1.37em;">
```